# Is a child bike seat allowed in flight?

Tags: child-safety-seats

Hello I am flying with my one year old baby. Is it allowed to check in a child bike seat (back seat) for free ?

Comment: Have you asked the airline ?

Comment: Which airline are you flying?

Answer (score 0):

It varies by airline, which is why commenters indicate you will need to provide that information to receive a concrete answer.  To use some local examples, [Qantas provides for a variety of infant items](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/checked-baggage/global/en#infants-and-children) which may include child bike seats (they aren't excluded, but you should check explicitly with the airline):

> **Infant Items**
>
> For each infant travelling with an adult, up to three
>   infant items, each weighing up to 32kg, can be carried free of charge
>   including:
>
> - Collapsible stroller or push-chair;
> - Collapsible cot or bassinet; and
> - Car seat or baby capsule.
>
> The additional allowances apply only on
>   Qantas operated flights with a QF flight number on the ticket.

[Virgin Australia has a similar policy](http://www.virginaustralia.com/us/en/plan/baggage/checked-baggage/):

> **Infants**
>
> Adults accompanying infants are entitled to carry infant special items
>   as checked baggage free of charge on Virgin Australia domestic
>   flights, irrespective of their combined weight. These items include,
>   but are not restricted to the following:
>
> - Pram/stroller
> - Portable cot
> - Car seat
> - Baby capsule
>
> If the adult does not have a baggage allowance the above items can
>   still be checked in free of charge. Other infant items, such as
>   clothing and toys, form part of the adult's baggage allowance.

As such both would probably allow a child bike seat to be included as free checked luggage, but it's not explicit.

However without a doubt other airlines will differ, depending upon their country/region (US vs European vs Middle East, etc), service status (full service would be more likely to provide for baggage allowances like the above, whereas budget services would be less likely) and domestic vs international flights.